# Override the same file from two modules so that both of the edits are shown?

Tags: magento2, module, template, requirejs

I have overridden a template file by specifying the path in `requirejs-config.js` file
like so:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
              'Magento_Checkout/template/form/element/email.html': 
              'Vendor_Module/template/form/element/email.html'
        }
  }
};
```

I tried to create a new module that overrides the same file with the same technique:

```
 var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                  'Magento_Checkout/template/form/element/email.html': 
                  'Vendor_AnotherModule/template/form/element/email.html'
            }
      }
    };
```

In the browser, I can see that only the second - `AnotherModule` is overriding and the changes from the first `Module` are being ignored.

How to override the same file from two different modules so that **both of the edits are shown?**

Comment: Please check my answer. I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need to manage the sequence of that both module. For more information please check following examples.

Update your `module.xml` file at `Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

And following code for Another Module.

Update your `module.xml` file at `Vendor/AnotherModule/etc/module.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_AnotherModule" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Once you made above changes you need to run following command.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Hope this will help you for what you want. :)

Comment: @konstantin-patroev have you tried this solution.? Is this working for you.?

Comment: Isn't the sequence only going to determine the order, therefore only showing changes from `AnotherModule`?

Comment: @KonstantinPatroev At last, try this because this solution work for me that's why I have suggested you.

Comment: @KonstantinPatroev Please let me know if these working for you?

Comment: Even if it worked I would have to have knowledge of what all the other extensions are overriding! This wouldn't be a good solution if i wanted it to be compatible with any other extensions

Comment: Got answer? I too need this..